# ServiceStack.Client Server Sent Events are not processed

Tags: c#, servicestack

I have a basic Hello World console program connecting to a web server but none of my callbacks are invoked (nothing gets printed to the console).

```
using ServiceStack;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("start ...");

            try
            {
                // http://docs.servicestack.net/csharp-server-events-client
                // ServiceSack.Client
                var client = new ServerEventsClient("http://localhost:9999/bus/api/v1/subscribe/karli/head/0")
                {
                    OnConnect = connectEvent => Console.WriteLine($"OnMessage {connectEvent}"),
                    OnCommand = cmd => Console.WriteLine($"OnCommand {cmd}"),
                    OnMessage = msg => Console.WriteLine($"OnMessage {msg}"),
                    OnUpdate = upd => Console.WriteLine($"OnUpdate {upd}"),
                    OnException = err => Console.WriteLine($"OnException {err}")
                }.Start();

                // keep main thread running ... 
                var a = Console.Read();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("dasda {0}", ex);
            }
        }

        private static void OnMessage(ServerEventMessage message)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"OnMessage {message}");
        }

    }
}
```

while the curl works as expected

```
$ curl "http://localhost:9999/bus/api/v1/subscribe/karli/head/0/event-stream"
{"key":"1","offset":0,"value":{}}
{"key":"1","offset":1,"value":{}}
{"key":"1","offset":2,"value":{}}
{"key":"1","offset":3,"value":{}}
{"key":"1","offset":4,"value":{}}
{"key":"1","offset":5,"value":{}}
{"key":"1","offset":6,"value":{}}
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ServerEventsClient` needs to be initialized with the **BaseUrl** where your ServiceStack Service is located. If you're not hosting ServiceStack at a custom path it would just be host name, e.g:

```
var client = new ServerEventsClient("http://localhost:9999/") {
///...
}.Start();
```

Comment: actually the server is a Java server, I thought SSE over http is pretty standard and stack independent. is this a problem?

Comment: @KIC Yes, it only works with [ServiceStack Server Events](http://docs.servicestack.net/server-events).

Comment: hmm that sucks is there something that actually works with any sse

Comment: @KIC i don’t know of any general purpose c# SSE clients

Comment: I use now EventSource4Net which works but only with a change in my java server, that's how standardisation works :-)